# Скрытие ответов в тестах

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sublime-text, sublime-text-3, pcre

Здравствуйте, имеются готовые текстовые документы с тестовыми заданиями. Их содержимое:

```
Тема 1: Стихийные бедствия.
Автор: Булат Фаттахов
10. Таким женским именем звали ураган, сильно повредивший Новый Орлеан.
Ответ: Катрина.
20. "Дождь лил четыре года, одиннадцать месяцев и два дня" именно там.
Ответ: в Макондо.
30. В 1883 году было извержение вулкана именно на этом острове.
Ответ: Кракатау (Остров назывался так же как и вулкан).
40. Армянские города Гюмри и Ванадзор, сильно пострадавшие во время землетрясения 1988 года, в советское время носили такие названия.
Ответ: Ленинакан и Кировокан.
50. Крупнейшее за всю историю человечества это стихийное бедствие произошло в 1875 году в США, а не в Египте двумя тысячами годами ранее.
Ответ: Нашествие саранчи.

Тема 2: Города России.
Автор: Булат Фаттахов
10. Это крупнейший город России после Москвы.
Ответ: Санкт-Петербург.
20. Москва крупнейший город России, а Тольятти тоже крупнейший город в России среди таких.
Ответ: Не являющийся столицей региона.
30. Это - крупнейший город самого большого острова России.
Ответ: Южно-Сахалинск.
40. Именно в этом городе происходит действие сериала "Счастливы вместе".
Ответ: Екатеринбург.
50. А именно этот город является самым западным городом России.
Ответ: Балтийск.
```

И так на протяжении всех файлов. я не хочу сразу видеть то, что содержится после «Ответ». Нужно, чтобы ответы изначально были скрыты, становясь видимыми только тогда, когда пользователь выполняет какое-то действие, например, нажимает на «Развернуть ответ».

Методы не имеют значения. Да, можно заключить ответы под спойлеры — в HTML, например, проще всего в тэг  — `Ответ:<details>Текст ответа</details>` (что он не поддерживается IE и Firefox, ничего страшного) . Но как выполнить множественные замены (учитывая, что ответы могут быть в несколько строк), например, при помощи программы Sublime Text, поддерживающей [регулярные выражения PCRE](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html)?

```
Ответ: 'Текст ответа'
20.

→

Ответ: <details>'Текст ответа'</details>
20.




Ответ: 'Текст ответа'

Тема

→

Ответ: <details>'Текст ответа'</details>

Тема
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если в конце ответа обязательно цифра следующего вопроса или пустая строка, за которые можно зацепиться, то в Sublime можно так:

- Find What: `^Ответ: ((.|\n)+?)\n([0-9\n])`
- Replace With: `Ответ: <details>\1</details>\n\3`
  (где `\1` и `\3` означают содержимое первой и третьей пар скобок в регулярке)

(Немного пояснений: `(.|\n)+` — берём один или больше любых символов, даже перенос строки, а `+?` — включаем ленивый режим работы вместо жадного, чтобы регулярка не считала одним ответом всё с начала первого ответа до конца последнего)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

В Notepad++ замена регулярные выражения с отмеченным флажком **И новые строки**.

## Исходный текст

```
Тема 1: Стихийные бедствия.
Автор: Булат Фаттахов
10. Таким женским именем звали ураган, сильно повредивший Новый Орлеан.
Ответ: Катрина.
20. "Дождь лил четыре года, одиннадцать месяцев и два дня" именно там.
Ответ: в Макондо.
30. В 1883 году было извержение вулкана именно на этом острове.
Ответ: Кракатау (Остров назывался так же как и вулкан).
40. Армянские города Гюмри и Ванадзор, сильно пострадавшие во время землетрясения 1988 года, в советское время носили такие названия.
Ответ: Ленинакан и Кировокан.
50. Крупнейшее за всю историю человечества это стихийное бедствие произошло в 1875 году в США, а не в Египте двумя тысячами годами ранее.
Ответ: Нашествие саранчи.

Тема 2: Города России.
Автор: Булат Фаттахов
10. Это крупнейший город России 
после Москвы.
Ответ: Санкт-Петербург.
20. Москва крупнейший город России, а Тольятти тоже крупнейший город в России среди таких.
Ответ: Не являющийся столицей региона.
30. Это - крупнейший город самого большого острова России.
Ответ: Южно-Сахалинск.
40. Именно в этом городе происходит действие сериала "Счастливы вместе".
Ответ: Екатеринбург.
50. А именно этот город является самым западным городом России.
Ответ: Балтийск.
```

## Замена 1:

```
((\d+)\. ((?!\r\nОтвет:).)+)
<input type=checkbox id=chk\2><label for=chk\2>\1</label>
```

Результат:

```
Тема 1: Стихийные бедствия.
Автор: Булат Фаттахов
<input type=checkbox id=chk10><label for=chk10>10. Таким женским именем звали ураган, сильно повредивший Новый Орлеан.</label>
Ответ: Катрина.
<input type=checkbox id=chk20><label for=chk20>20. "Дождь лил четыре года, одиннадцать месяцев и два дня" именно там.</label>
Ответ: в Макондо.
<input type=checkbox id=chk30><label for=chk30>30. В 1883 году было извержение вулкана именно на этом острове.</label>
Ответ: Кракатау (Остров назывался так же как и вулкан).
<input type=checkbox id=chk40><label for=chk40>40. Армянские города Гюмри и Ванадзор, сильно пострадавшие во время землетрясения 1988 года, в советское время носили такие названия.</label>
Ответ: Ленинакан и Кировокан.
<input type=checkbox id=chk50><label for=chk50>50. Крупнейшее за всю историю человечества это стихийное бедствие произошло в 1875 году в США, а не в Египте двумя тысячами годами ранее.</label>
Ответ: Нашествие
саранчи.

Тема 2: Города России.
Автор: Булат Фаттахов
<input type=checkbox id=chk10><label for=chk10>10. Это крупнейший город России 
после Москвы.</label>
Ответ: Санкт-Петербург.
<input type=checkbox id=chk20><label for=chk20>20. Москва крупнейший город России, а Тольятти тоже крупнейший город в России среди таких.</label>
Ответ: Не являющийся столицей региона.
<input type=checkbox id=chk30><label for=chk30>30. Это - крупнейший город самого большого острова России.</label>
Ответ: Южно-Сахалинск.
<input type=checkbox id=chk40><label for=chk40>40. Именно в этом городе происходит действие сериала "Счастливы вместе".</label>
Ответ: Екатеринбург.
<input type=checkbox id=chk50><label for=chk50>50. А именно этот город является самым западным городом России.</label>
Ответ: Балтийск.
```

## Замена 2:

```
(</label>\r\n)(Ответ: ((?!\r\n(Тема:|<input)).)+)
\1<div>\2</div>
```

Результат:

```
Тема 1: Стихийные бедствия.
Автор: Булат Фаттахов
<input type=checkbox id=chk10><label for=chk10>10. Таким женским именем звали ураган, сильно повредивший Новый Орлеан.</label>
<div>Ответ: Катрина.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk20><label for=chk20>20. "Дождь лил четыре года, одиннадцать месяцев и два дня" именно там.</label>
<div>Ответ: в Макондо.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk30><label for=chk30>30. В 1883 году было извержение вулкана именно на этом острове.</label>
<div>Ответ: Кракатау (Остров назывался так же как и вулкан).</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk40><label for=chk40>40. Армянские города Гюмри и Ванадзор, сильно пострадавшие во время землетрясения 1988 года, в советское время носили такие названия.</label>
<div>Ответ: Ленинакан и Кировокан.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk50><label for=chk50>50. Крупнейшее за всю историю человечества это стихийное бедствие произошло в 1875 году в США, а не в Египте двумя тысячами годами ранее.</label>
<div>Ответ: Нашествие
саранчи.

Тема 2: Города России.
Автор: Булат Фаттахов</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk10><label for=chk10>10. Это крупнейший город России 
после Москвы.</label>
<div>Ответ: Санкт-Петербург.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk20><label for=chk20>20. Москва крупнейший город России, а Тольятти тоже крупнейший город в России среди таких.</label>
<div>Ответ: Не являющийся столицей региона.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk30><label for=chk30>30. Это - крупнейший город самого большого острова России.</label>
<div>Ответ: Южно-Сахалинск.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk40><label for=chk40>40. Именно в этом городе происходит действие сериала "Счастливы вместе".</label>
<div>Ответ: Екатеринбург.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk50><label for=chk50>50. А именно этот город является самым западным городом России.</label>
<div>Ответ: Балтийск.</div>
```

## Замена 3:

```
(Тема (\d+).*?)(\r\n<input)
<h1 id=sec-\2>\1</h1>\3
```

Результат:

```
<h1 id=sec-1>Тема 1: Стихийные бедствия.
Автор: Булат Фаттахов</h1>
<input type=checkbox id=chk10><label for=chk10>10. Таким женским именем звали ураган, сильно повредивший Новый Орлеан.</label>
<div>Ответ: Катрина.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk20><label for=chk20>20. "Дождь лил четыре года, одиннадцать месяцев и два дня" именно там.</label>
<div>Ответ: в Макондо.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk30><label for=chk30>30. В 1883 году было извержение вулкана именно на этом острове.</label>
<div>Ответ: Кракатау (Остров назывался так же как и вулкан).</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk40><label for=chk40>40. Армянские города Гюмри и Ванадзор, сильно пострадавшие во время землетрясения 1988 года, в советское время носили такие названия.</label>
<div>Ответ: Ленинакан и Кировокан.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk50><label for=chk50>50. Крупнейшее за всю историю человечества это стихийное бедствие произошло в 1875 году в США, а не в Египте двумя тысячами годами ранее.</label>
<div>Ответ: Нашествие
саранчи.

<h1 id=sec-2>Тема 2: Города России.
Автор: Булат Фаттахов</div></h1>
<input type=checkbox id=chk10><label for=chk10>10. Это крупнейший город России 
после Москвы.</label>
<div>Ответ: Санкт-Петербург.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk20><label for=chk20>20. Москва крупнейший город России, а Тольятти тоже крупнейший город в России среди таких.</label>
<div>Ответ: Не являющийся столицей региона.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk30><label for=chk30>30. Это - крупнейший город самого большого острова России.</label>
<div>Ответ: Южно-Сахалинск.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk40><label for=chk40>40. Именно в этом городе происходит действие сериала "Счастливы вместе".</label>
<div>Ответ: Екатеринбург.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk50><label for=chk50>50. А именно этот город является самым западным городом России.</label>
<div>Ответ: Балтийск.</div>
```

## Замена 4:

```
(id=sec-(\d+).*?)(id|for)(=chk)(\d+)
\1\3\4-\2-\5
```

**Нажимать <kbd>Заменить все</kbd> до тех пор, пока количество замен не станет равным нулю**.
Это будет в 2 раза больше нажатий, чем вопросов в самой большой теме.
В принципе, можно уменьшить число нажатий вдвое.

Результат:

```
<h1 id=sec-1>Тема 1: Стихийные бедствия.
Автор: Булат Фаттахов</h1>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-1-10><label for=chk-1-10>10. Таким женским именем звали ураган, сильно повредивший Новый Орлеан.</label>
<div>Ответ: Катрина.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-1-20><label for=chk-1-20>20. "Дождь лил четыре года, одиннадцать месяцев и два дня" именно там.</label>
<div>Ответ: в Макондо.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-1-30><label for=chk-1-30>30. В 1883 году было извержение вулкана именно на этом острове.</label>
<div>Ответ: Кракатау (Остров назывался так же как и вулкан).</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-1-40><label for=chk-1-40>40. Армянские города Гюмри и Ванадзор, сильно пострадавшие во время землетрясения 1988 года, в советское время носили такие названия.</label>
<div>Ответ: Ленинакан и Кировокан.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-1-50><label for=chk-1-50>50. Крупнейшее за всю историю человечества это стихийное бедствие произошло в 1875 году в США, а не в Египте двумя тысячами годами ранее.</label>
<div>Ответ: Нашествие
саранчи.

<h1 id=sec-2>Тема 2: Города России.
Автор: Булат Фаттахов</div></h1>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-2-10><label for=chk-2-10>10. Это крупнейший город России 
после Москвы.</label>
<div>Ответ: Санкт-Петербург.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-2-20><label for=chk-2-20>20. Москва крупнейший город России, а Тольятти тоже крупнейший город в России среди таких.</label>
<div>Ответ: Не являющийся столицей региона.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-2-30><label for=chk-2-30>30. Это - крупнейший город самого большого острова России.</label>
<div>Ответ: Южно-Сахалинск.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-2-40><label for=chk-2-40>40. Именно в этом городе происходит действие сериала "Счастливы вместе".</label>
<div>Ответ: Екатеринбург.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-2-50><label for=chk-2-50>50. А именно этот город является самым западным городом России.</label>
<div>Ответ: Балтийск.</div>
```

## Замена 5 (исправляем косяк, сделанный раньше)

```
(\s*<h1(?:(?!<h1).)*)(</div>)(</h1>)
\2\1\3
```

## Добавляем немного css:

```css
input { display: none; }

input + label + div { display: none; }
input:checked + label + div { display: block; }

label { display: block; cursor: pointer; margin-top: 1em; }
label:hover { color: blue; }
label, div, h1 { white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

```html
<h1 id=sec-1>Тема 1: Стихийные бедствия.
Автор: Булат Фаттахов</h1>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-1-10><label for=chk-1-10>10. Таким женским именем звали ураган, сильно повредивший Новый Орлеан.</label>
<div>Ответ: Катрина.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-1-20><label for=chk-1-20>20. "Дождь лил четыре года, одиннадцать месяцев и два дня" именно там.</label>
<div>Ответ: в Макондо.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-1-30><label for=chk-1-30>30. В 1883 году было извержение вулкана именно на этом острове.</label>
<div>Ответ: Кракатау (Остров назывался так же как и вулкан).</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-1-40><label for=chk-1-40>40. Армянские города Гюмри и Ванадзор, сильно пострадавшие во время землетрясения 1988 года, в советское время носили такие названия.</label>
<div>Ответ: Ленинакан и Кировокан.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-1-50><label for=chk-1-50>50. Крупнейшее за всю историю человечества это стихийное бедствие произошло в 1875 году в США, а не в Египте двумя тысячами годами ранее.</label>
<div>Ответ: Нашествие
саранчи.</div>

<h1 id=sec-2>Тема 2: Города России.
Автор: Булат Фаттахов</h1>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-2-10><label for=chk-2-10>10. Это крупнейший город России 
после Москвы.</label>
<div>Ответ: Санкт-Петербург.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-2-20><label for=chk-2-20>20. Москва крупнейший город России, а Тольятти тоже крупнейший город в России среди таких.</label>
<div>Ответ: Не являющийся столицей региона.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-2-30><label for=chk-2-30>30. Это - крупнейший город самого большого острова России.</label>
<div>Ответ: Южно-Сахалинск.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-2-40><label for=chk-2-40>40. Именно в этом городе происходит действие сериала "Счастливы вместе".</label>
<div>Ответ: Екатеринбург.</div>
<input type=checkbox id=chk-2-50><label for=chk-2-50>50. А именно этот город является самым западным городом России.</label>
<div>Ответ: Балтийск.</div>
```

Comment: Хм.. Пункт 4 можно заменить несколькими, но убрать многократное нажатие кнопки. Ну и вместо пункта 5 следовало бы поправить пункт 1: `((\d+)\. ((?!(\r\n)+(Ответ|Тема):).)+)`.

Comment: [Обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27938195#27938195)

Comment: Qwertiy, похоже, понял, в чём разница между PCRE Sublime Text и Notepad++ . В ST, [судя по всему](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/regex-carriage-return-not-found/7986/2), [как в Unix-подобных ОС](https://i.gyazo.com/0524260d2ecfabb0fe3e500ef286f80e.png), достаточно метасимвола `\n`, использование же метасимвола `\r` — перевода каретки — будет ошибочным. Полагаю, необходимо отредактировать ответ с учётом специфики Sublime Text. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Т. к. вопрос практический, позволю себе дополнить [ответ ув-мого andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/498603/199934).

Сначала желательно заменить слово или фразу, при нажатии на которое выводится спойлер, — например, в Chrome это «Подробнее», — при помощи тега `<summary>`. Если хотим кликать сразу на «Ответ», замена выйдет следующей:

- **Find What:** `^Ответ: ((.|\n)+?)\n([0-9\n])`
- **Replace With**: `<details><summary>Ответ:</summary>\1</details>\n\3`

[image: Замена для тестов]

Затем, чтобы тэги отображись в Firefox, Edge и Opera Mini, требуется подключить скрипт [Details-Polyfill](https://github.com/uniqname/Details-Polyfill/blob/master/details.polyfill.js). Для Эксплорера, к сожалению, и этот метод не работает, проверял на [IE NetRenderer](http://netrenderer.com/index.php). Принцип действия скрипта: если браузер поддерживает `<details>` и `<summary>`, то ничего не происходит; не поддерживает — задействуется. Когда спойлеров множество, то, увы, достаточно продолжительное время, почему от просмотра в Firefox лучше всё же воздержаться.

Итог см. в коде.

```js
/* Licensed under the MIT license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php */
(function (doc) {
'use strict';
var i, j,
textWrapper,
idCount = 0,
rootNode = doc.documentElement,
headElem = doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || rootNode,
bodyElem = doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] || rootNode,
detailStyleTag = doc.createElement('style'),
rules = 'details { display: block; overflow:hidden; } \n' +
'details[open] { height: auto; } \n' +
'summary { display:inline-block; } \n' +
'details * { visibility: hidden; } \n' +
'summary:first-child { visibility: visible; cursor: pointer; } \n' +
'details[open] * { visibility: visible } \n' +
'details[open] summary { margin-bottom: 0; }',
/* Technically, a summary element has a "Phrasing content" model and should be displayed inline.
* see http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-summary-element,
* http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#phrasing-content
*
* FYI: Chrome currently and incorrectly treats the <summary> element as block level.
*/
addRule = function (styleTag, rule) {
if (styleTag.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'style') {
if (!!styleTag['styleSheet'] && styleTag.styleSheet['cssText'] !== undefined) { //for MSIE
styleTag.styleSheet.cssText += '\n' + rule;
} else { styleTag.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('\n' + rule)); }
}
},
addEvent = function (el, eventName, f) {
//W3C event biding
if (el.addEventListener) {
el.addEventListener(eventName, f);
//IE event binding
} else if (el.attachEvent) {
el.attachEvent('on' + eventName, f);
// Fallback, but don't overwrite a preexisting "onclick" attribute.
} else if (el['on' + eventName] === null) {
el['on' + eventName] = f;
}
},
toggle = function (e) {
/* When a <summary> element is clicked the parent <details> element's "open"
* attribute needs to be toggled to maintain the attribute's reflective nature.
* see http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-details-open
*/
var detailsElmnt,
target = e.target || e.srcElement;
if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'summary') {
detailsElmnt = target;
while (detailsElmnt.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'details') {
detailsElmnt = detailsElmnt.parentNode;
//Break if we get to the root node without finding a details element.
if (detailsElmnt === bodyElem) {
detailsElmnt = null;
break;
}
}
if (detailsElmnt) {
if (detailsElmnt.getAttribute('open')) {
detailsElmnt.removeAttribute('open');
} else { detailsElmnt.setAttribute('open', 'open'); }
bodyElem.className = bodyElem.className;
}
}
},
init = function () {
var detailsID,
detailsElem,
summaryElem,
height, //height of the summary element
detailsElems = doc.getElementsByTagName('details');
for (i = 0; i < detailsElems.length; i++) {
detailsElem = detailsElems[i];
if (!detailsElem.getAttribute('data-detailsid')) {
detailsID = 'd' + (idCount++);
detailsElem.className += (' ' + detailsID);
detailsElem.setAttribute('data-detailsID', detailsID);
/* The spec expects the functional <summary> element to be the first child node of a
* <details> element. In practice, it appears the first child <summary> element of a
* <detials> element is enlisted as the functional <summary> element and displayed as
* though it were the first child. For our purposes, we will do that explicitly.
* Additionaly, If a <summary> element does not exist, a default toggle is provided.
*/
summaryElem = detailsElem.getElementsByTagName('summary')[0];
if (!summaryElem) {
summaryElem = doc.createElement('summary');
summaryElem.appendChild(doc.createTextNode('Details'));
detailsElem.insertBefore(summaryElem, detailsElem.firstChild);
} else if ( summaryElem !== detailsElem.firstChild) {
detailsElem.removeChild(summaryElem);
detailsElem.insertBefore(summaryElem, detailsElem.firstChild);
}
height = summaryElem.offsetHeight;
addRule(detailStyleTag, 'details.' + detailsID + ' { height: ' + height + 'px; }\n' +
'details.' + detailsID + '[open] { height: auto; }');
//Text nodes are killing me here. Thanks to @Remy for the solve.
// Weighing the pros and cons of using a standard element like <span> or <b> vs a non-standard
// but more semantically meaninfull <text> element, I think <text> wins, though not without some
// regret.
for (j = 0; j < detailsElem.childNodes.length; j++ ) {
if (detailsElem.childNodes[j].nodeName === '#text' && (detailsElem.childNodes[j].nodeValue||'').replace(/\s/g, '').length) {
textWrapper = document.createElement('text');
textWrapper.appendChild(detailsElem.childNodes[j]);
detailsElem.insertBefore(textWrapper, detailsElem.childNodes[j]);
}
}
}
}
};
/*
* The inserted stylesheet needs to be first so as to have a minimal cascading coeffecient.
* It also needs to be added to the DOM before IE can access it's properties.
* The polyfill only adds default or necessary styling and should not interfere with other style rules.
*/
headElem.insertBefore(detailStyleTag, headElem.firstChild);
init();
addRule(detailStyleTag, rules);
addEvent(bodyElem, 'click', toggle);
addEvent(bodyElem, 'DOMSubtreeModified', init);
}(document, undefined));
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>details</title>
        <script>
            /*yepnope1.0.2|WTFPL*/
            (function(a,b,c){function H(){var a=z;a.loader={load:G,i:0};return a}function G(a,b,c){var e=b=="c"?r:q;i=0,b=b||"j",u(a)?F(e,a,b,this.i++,d,c):(h.splice(this.i++,0,a),h.length==1&&E());return this}function F(a,c,d,g,j,l){function q(){!o&&A(n.readyState)&&(p.r=o=1,!i&&B(),n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=null,e(function(){m.removeChild(n)},0))}var n=b.createElement(a),o=0,p={t:d,s:c,e:l};n.src=n.data=c,!k&&(n.style.display="none"),n.width=n.height="0",a!="object"&&(n.type=d),n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=q,a=="img"?n.onerror=q:a=="script"&&(n.onerror=function(){p.e=p.r=1,E()}),h.splice(g,0,p),m.insertBefore(n,k?null:f),e(function(){o||(m.removeChild(n),p.r=p.e=o=1,B())},z.errorTimeout)}function E(){var a=h.shift();i=1,a?a.t?e(function(){a.t=="c"?D(a):C(a)},0):(a(),B()):i=0}function D(a){var c=b.createElement("link"),d;c.href=a.s,c.rel="stylesheet",c.type="text/css";if(!a.e&&(o||j)){var g=function(a){e(function(){if(!d)try{a.sheet.cssRules.length?(d=1,B()):g(a)}catch(b){b.code==1e3||b.message=="security"||b.message=="denied"?(d=1,e(function(){B()},0)):g(a)}},0)};g(c)}else c.onload=function(){d||(d=1,e(function(){B()},0))},a.e&&c.onload();e(function(){d||(d=1,B())},z.errorTimeout),!a.e&&f.parentNode.insertBefore(c,f)}function C(a){var c=b.createElement("script"),d;c.src=a.s,c.onreadystatechange=c.onload=function(){!d&&A(c.readyState)&&(d=1,B(),c.onload=c.onreadystatechange=null)},e(function(){d||(d=1,B())},z.errorTimeout),a.e?c.onload():f.parentNode.insertBefore(c,f)}function B(){var a=1,b=-1;while(h.length- ++b)if(h[b].s&&!(a=h[b].r))break;a&&E()}function A(a){return!a||a=="loaded"||a=="complete"}var d=b.documentElement,e=a.setTimeout,f=b.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],g={}.toString,h=[],i=0,j="MozAppearance"in d.style,k=j&&!!b.createRange().compareNode,l=j&&!k,m=k?d:f.parentNode,n=a.opera&&g.call(a.opera)=="[object Opera]",o="webkitAppearance"in d.style,p=o&&"async"in b.createElement("script"),q=j?"object":n||p?"img":"script",r=o?"img":q,s=Array.isArray||function(a){return g.call(a)=="[object Array]"},t=function(a){return Object(a)===a},u=function(a){return typeof a=="string"},v=function(a){return g.call(a)=="[object Function]"},w=[],x={},y,z;z=function(a){function h(a,b){function i(a){if(u(a))g(a,f,b,0,c);else if(t(a))for(h in a)a.hasOwnProperty(h)&&g(a[h],f,b,h,c)}var c=!!a.test,d=c?a.yep:a.nope,e=a.load||a.both,f=a.callback,h;i(d),i(e),a.complete&&b.load(a.complete)}function g(a,b,d,e,g){var h=f(a),i=h.autoCallback;if(!h.bypass){b&&(b=v(b)?b:b[a]||b[e]||b[a.split("/").pop().split("?")[0]]);if(h.instead)return h.instead(a,b,d,e,g);d.load(h.url,h.forceCSS||!h.forceJS&&/css$/.test(h.url)?"c":c,h.noexec),(v(b)||v(i))&&d.load(function(){H(),b&&b(h.origUrl,g,e),i&&i(h.origUrl,g,e)})}}function f(a){var b=a.split("!"),c=w.length,d=b.pop(),e=b.length,f={url:d,origUrl:d,prefixes:b},g,h;for(h=0;h<e;h++)g=x[b[h]],g&&(f=g(f));for(h=0;h<c;h++)f=w[h](f);return f}var b,d,e=this.yepnope.loader;if(u(a))g(a,0,e,0);else if(s(a))for(b=0;b<a.length;b++)d=a[b],u(d)?g(d,0,e,0):s(d)?z(d):t(d)&&h(d,e);else t(a)&&h(a,e)},z.addPrefix=function(a,b){x[a]=b},z.addFilter=function(a){w.push(a)},z.errorTimeout=1e4,b.readyState==null&&b.addEventListener&&(b.readyState="loading",b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",y=function(){b.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",y,0),b.readyState="complete"},0)),a.yepnope=H()})(this,this.document)

        </script>

        <script >
            var Supports = {
                details: ('open' in document.createElement('details'))
            };
            yepnope({
                test: Supports.details,
                nope: 'js/details.polyfill.js'
            });
        </script>

 </head> 

<body>

Тема 1: Стихийные бедствия.
Автор: Булат Фаттахов
10. Таким женским именем звали ураган, сильно повредивший Новый Орлеан.
<details><summary>Ответ:</summary>Катрина.</details>
20. "Дождь лил четыре года, одиннадцать месяцев и два дня" именно там.
<details><summary>Ответ:</summary>в Макондо.</details>
30. В 1883 году было извержение вулкана именно на этом острове.
<details><summary>Ответ:</summary>Кракатау (Остров назывался так же как и вулкан).</details>
40. Армянские города Гюмри и Ванадзор, сильно пострадавшие во время землетрясения 1988 года, в советское время носили такие названия.
<details><summary>Ответ:</summary>Ленинакан и Кировокан.</details>
50. Крупнейшее за всю историю человечества это стихийное бедствие произошло в 1875 году в США, а не в Египте двумя тысячами годами ранее.
<details><summary>Ответ:</summary>Нашествие саранчи.</details>

Тема 2: Города России.
Автор: Булат Фаттахов
10. Это крупнейший город России после Москвы.
<details><summary>Ответ:</summary>Санкт-Петербург.</details>
20. Москва крупнейший город России, а Тольятти тоже крупнейший город в России среди таких.
<details><summary>Ответ:</summary>Не являющийся столицей региона.</details>
30. Это - крупнейший город самого большого острова России.
<details><summary>Ответ:</summary>Южно-Сахалинск.</details>
40. Именно в этом городе происходит действие сериала "Счастливы вместе".
<details><summary>Ответ:</summary>Екатеринбург.</details>
50. А именно этот город является самым западным городом России.
<details><summary>Ответ:</summary>Балтийск.</details>

</body> 
</html>
```

**UPD**: начиная с 47-й версии Firefox [поддерживает](http://caniuse.com/#search=summary) теги `<summary>` и `<details>`. Чтобы увидеть в Firefox действие тегов, пользователю необходимо ввести в адресную строку этого браузера `about:config` → Я обещаю, что буду осторожен → в строке поиска найти параметр `dom.details_element.enabled` → установить ему значение `true`.